# Pandas, Plotly grouping seconds without resample

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I'm trying to graph my csv but my dataset contains unix timestamps which is in milliseconds.

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label
1588241066948,438,HTTP Request
1588241066909,490,HTTP Request
1588241066911,470,HTTP Request
1588241066913,461,HTTP Request
1588241066913,461,HTTP Request
1588241066913,460,HTTP Request
1588241066913,460,HTTP Request
1588241066913,460,HTTP Request
1588241066914,476,HTTP Request
1588241066913,478,HTTP Request
1588241066913,461,HTTP Request
```

currently my graphs are plotting per ms. I cannot use resample as it drops the labels. 
Ultimately i would like to get the 95th percentile for every second or minute and plot the points.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('demo.csv', low_memory=False)

df['timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeStamp'],unit='ms')

fig = px.line(df, x = 'timeStamp', y = 'elapsed', color = 'label', title='Line Graph')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you create DataFrame from sample data which can be ploted? Are data [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: yes i can ive added the sample dataframe

Comment: Thank you for code, but my comment was about something else. Do you check link? Can you create expected output for plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `DatetimeIndex`, so is possible use [`DataFrameGroupBy.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html) - grouping chained with resample:

```
df['timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeStamp'],unit='ms')

df1 = (df.set_index('timeStamp')
         .groupby('label')['elapsed']
         .resample('S')
         .quantile(0.95)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
          label           timeStamp  elapsed
0  HTTP Request 2020-04-30 10:04:26    484.0
```

Comment: Amazing its what I'm after